# filter in redshift sql

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following query in prostagesql

```
SELECT s_campaign_id,  COUNT(b_entry_type_tag)::decimal * 1 AS tags,COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv) AS conversions,
COALESCE ( SUM ( f_revenue ) FILTER(WHERE d_gen_date>='2020-12-01'AND
d_gen_date<='2020-12-01'), 0 ) AS revenue2 FROM tbl_reports WHERE
(d_gen_date>='2021-01-18' AND d_gen_date<='2021-01-24') GROUP BY s_campaign_id
```

but in redshift it will not recognize the FILTER and I get syntax error
how can this query work with redshift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `SUM` with a `CASE` expression instead:

```sql
SELECT
    s_campaign_id,
    COUNT(b_entry_type_tag)::decimal * 1 AS tags,
    COUNT(b_entry_type_cnv) AS conversions,
    SUM(CASE WHEN d_gen_date BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2020-12-01'
             THEN f_revenue ELSE 0 END) AS revenue2
FROM tbl_reports
WHERE
   d_gen_date BETWEEN '2021-01-18' AND '2021-01-24'
GROUP BY
    s_campaign_id;
```